# Get comment count on specific URL from Google+ comment box - Google+ API

Tags: google-api, google-plus, social-networking

I have a Google+ comment box on my WordPress blog.

It posts comments specific to the window.location of each post - so it can display comments that were made with comment box at that exact URL (below the comment box).

This works great - I would however like to display the total number of Google+ comments at the top of the post as well...

Is there a way to query the G+ API for this info?

I have poured over the Google documentation and unfortunately I don't speak software engineer fluently!

If you want the link to a post (it's just lorem ipsum right now): 
http://www.thedesignlabproject.com/frontPage/post6/

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no APIs for the Google+ comments widget. You can perform a [search](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/search) for public comments that were shared to Google+ but that's about it. If you would like to see an API you should [file feature requests](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list).

Comment: see my question then is about this line:

Comment: I just can't figure out if that or some other property may be able to either return a simple integer count or some json maybe that I can use in a roundabout kind of way to determine the total...

Comment: Any thoughts on this? Do you have any experience with this API?

Comment: The supported gapi API methods for Google+ are listed [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/javascript). Anything not listed there is not recommended for use as it could disappear or change without warning.

Comment: I see - so it might be possible but it can't be relied on in the long term. So it is what it is then! Thanks again :)